# How to simulate low RAM on a machine?

Tags: performance

On an old build there was a problem with one component that consumed a lot of RAM. As a result, another component started failing with a wrong error message. The first component has been fixed and does not consume extra memory now.

However, I want to verify that second component was fixed, and in order to do that, I need  a way to decrease the amount of free RAM. Any guidance on how to do that?

Comment: There was no 'stress-testing' tag, and I couldn't create one due to low reputation points

Comment: In the iphone simulator you select "low ram warning" :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's some ideas here on this old StackExchange question which should hopefully help you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2285701/how-do-i-limit-ram-to-test-low-memory-situations